# Complex sharing permissions on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, permissions

I have a folder on Google Drive for a small group that I manage, let's call that the Master folder. Within it are a load of sub-folders (around 20). The main folder acts like a kind of 'drive' in itself. Each sub-folder is only relevant to some people though, and each person might only need access to 5-10 of the folders. Some information is also kind of private so, as the group expands, we want to make sure only the people who need to have access these files, do.

At the moment, the Master folder is shared with everyone, which gives access to all sub-folders by default.
I want to create easy sharing permissions so that when someone is added, we can select which of the subfolders they have access to.

Sharing the sub-folders individually is not ideal as it's time consuming. Additionally the sharing accounts are usually people's personal Drive accounts so it means you would end up with a bunch of these sub-folders in your own Google Drive, and have to organise them yourself. Much nicer to have our Master folder shared, and be able to only see the folders you have permission for.

I've used CRM tools before where you can set hierarchical permissions, where User X has access to folders A, D, and F, and User Y has access to folders A, C, and E, etc.. Is this possible in Google drive?

Comment: You can already have sub-folders have different permissions than the parent in Drive; it sounds like you're looking for an easier way to scale this?

 I'd recommend grouping users with Google Groups and adding the group email, or even better, having a G Suite account create Team Drives to add them to.